# Is there any explicit support for modulo operation in eplex library

Tags: prolog, constraints, eclipse-clp

I am using `eplex` and `ic` library and trying to solve a problem. I see that the `eplex` and `ic` provide explicit support for `addition,multiplication` and `subtraction` but there is no support for `modulo` or `division`.

More precisely, I have this code :

```
    FirstResult #=  (Result[I] mod Val), % Here it gives error because Result[I] is not instantiated.
    NewVal is Val+1,
    SecondResult #= (Result[I] mod NewVal)
```

and `mod` requires its two arguments to be ground but `Result[I]` is not instantiated, rather it has range of values. So my question is how such constraints which involve `mod` operation can be delayed.

Answer (score 1):

You can normally reformulate

```
R #= X mod Y
```

as

```
0 #=< R, R #=< Y-1,      %  R is between 0 and Y-1
X #= _*Y + R,            %  X is some multiple of Y, plus a remainder R
```

This assumes you are using `library(ic)` and you don't have any special requirements for the behaviour with negative arguments.

For `library(eplex)`, which uses a MILP solver, you can do almost the same (as long as Y is an integer parameter), but you have to be a bit more explicit about integrality:

```
0 $=< R, R $=< Y-1,
integers([K,R]),
X $= K*Y + R,
```